# Access file on docker using JavaScript/Node

Tags: node.js, docker

Is there a way to programatically access a file on a container (docker) during execution. I've tried using node-docker-api just to set things up in the first instance, and establish a connection:

```
const docker = new Docker({
    "host": "tcp://docker:port"
});

// List
docker.container.list()
// Inspect
    .then(containers => containers[0].status())
    .then(container => container.top())
    .then(processes => console.log(processes))
    .catch(error => console.log(error));
```

where "port" is the 4 digit port number. But I get this error message:

```
{ Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:80
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1081:14)
  errno: 'ECONNREFUSED',
  code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
  syscall: 'connect',
  address: '127.0.0.1',
  port: 80 }
```

UPDATE:
I have done something similar in Java with dockerjava using https://github.com/docker-java/docker-java/issues/253 and httphijack - https://gist.github.com/missedone/76517e618486db746056

```
ExecCreateCmdResponse execCreateResp = dck.execCreateCmd(cid).withCmd("bash")
        .withAttachStderr().withAttachStdout().withAttachStdin().withTty(false).exec();

HashMap<String, String> headers = new HashMap<>();
headers.put("Content-Type", "application/json");

HttpHijack ws = new HttpHijack(new URI("http://127.0.0.1:2376/v1.19/exec/" + execCreateResp.getId() + "/start"));
String payload = "{\"Detach\": false,\"Tty\": false}";
ws.post(headers, payload);
```

and then copying the file from the container using:

```
try (TarArchiveInputStream tarStream = new TarArchiveInputStream(
    docker.copyArchiveFromContainerCmd(containerId, "/home/seluser/Downloads/" + fileName).exec())) {
    unTar(tarStream, new File(filePath));
    return;
}catch(NotFoundException e){
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

But I can't seem to find an approach to achieve the above using javascript/node

Answer (score 1):

Given that the files inside the container are ephemeral you should be careful if your code somehow relies on that files.

The best practice is to use [docker volumes](https://docs.docker.com/storage/) to store data. 
In your case, if you can store files in a docker volume, then you can run your code from another container and see that files from it. So, containers will share the same storage, which is not ephemeral and will survive container restarts.

If docker volumes are not your case, then the single idea in my mind is to play with [Docker REST API](https://docs.docker.com/engine/api/v1.39/) and especially with an [Exec](https://docs.docker.com/engine/api/v1.39/#operation/ContainerExec) method.

Using this method you can execute the Linux commands in a container.

---

**UPDATE 1:**
If your program runs on a host machine and you need to have access to data generated by docker volume, you can also bind host machine directory to the directory inside docker container.

An example: `docker run -v /host/folder:/container/folder <your_image>`

This way any change in docker folder will be reflected on folder in your host machine - so you can access them.

[Read more](https://docs.docker.com/storage/bind-mounts/)

---

**UPDATE 2:**
You can use Docker REST API to execute commands inside docker container in the next way:

1. **Enable TCP access to the REST API:**
   Edit `/lib/systemd/system/docker.service` and change the next line:
   `ExecStart=/usr/bin/dockerd -g /data/docker -H fd://` to `ExecStart=/usr/bin/dockerd -H fd:// -H tcp://0.0.0.0:2375`
   and save the file.
   Then `systemctl daemon-reload` and `service docker restart`. Now you should be able to access the API on `http://127.0.0.1:2375` - you should get `{ "message": "page not found" }` as a response.
2. **Create an Exec object using REST API, example:**

```
curl --header "Content-Type: application/json" \
  --request POST \
  --data '{"AttachStdout": true,"AttachStderr": true,"Cmd": ["date"]}' \
http://127.0.0.1:2375/v{dockerVersion}/containers/{containerId}/exec
```

Here:

- `dockerVersion` - the version of your docker engine, could be retrieved using `docker version` command (see version fo the server, in my case it's 1.38 - so in URL it will be like v1.38 **don't forget `v`**)
- `containerId` - id of your container in docker, could be retrieved by following command: `curl http://127.0.0.1:2375/v{dockerVersion}/containers/json`

In response to `/containers/{containerId}/exec` you should get something like: `{"Id": "{objectId}"}`

3. **Execute previously created command:**

```
curl --header "Content-Type: application/json" \
  --request POST \
  --data '{"Detach": false,"Tty": false}' \
http://127.0.0.1:2375/v{dockerVersion}/exec/{objectId}/start
```

Here:

- `objectId` - id returned from docker API in previous step (STEP 2)

As a response you should get a plain text - the output of your command.

**NOTE:** The `Cmd` in JSON body is an array, so you can specify multiple commands.

Comment: thanks for the links.The files I need access to are generated during execution and need to be accessed seconds afterwards i.e. need to be copied into the working directory where the code is running from and processed. Do you have any example of how to interact with the container using your suggested approach. I can't find any examples on the link you provided. Thanks

Comment: Can't you store the generated files in a docker volume?

Comment: basically I'm running some selenium UI tests using selenium docker. During those tests, files are downloaded and I'm trying to access them after the download. The tests will be running as part of a CI process on Jenkins

Comment: Please, see my updated answer. You can bind selenium folder in docker to your host directory and access files in it. But probably there should some elegant solution.  I'm not familiar with selenium.

Comment: that would have been a nice solution if I was the only one using the container, but this is not the case. Rather than running docker with a host folder that everyone can access, it will be nice to be able to access the container during execution and copy the files over to the working directory. I have achieved this with Java using dockerjava but can't seem to find any solution using javascript/node

Comment: meant to say 'rather than trying to find a common host folder' that everyone can access

Comment: please see my update, just to provide more info on how it was implemented in java

Comment: @Larry, check `UPDATE 2` section of my answer. I made a small research and added instructions of how to execute linux commands inside docker container using REST API

Comment: Hi @Larry if this or any answer has solved your question please consider accepting it by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Docker API /getAchive method to extract files from a container, and then untar them
There is a NodeJS implementation of the docker API to use on the server side [dockerode](https://github.com/apocas/dockerode)

```
 npm i dockerode
```

Then import it and run the container where the file is

```js
var Docker = require('dockerode');
var docker = new Docker({socketPath: '/var/run/docker.sock'}); //or whatever path to your socket
let file="abs/path/in/container/somefile.file"
let tag="docekerImageTag"  //"repo/image" //"johndoe/docker_image"

runContainer(tag,"foo").then(container=>{
  getFile(container,file,ws)
})


function runContainer(containerName,param){
 return docker.run(
    containerName,
    ['Rscript', 'random.rscript','--test',`${param}`,],
    [process.stdout, process.stderr], {Tty:false}, //send only stdout if you don't want the split no tty needed
  ).then(function(data){
      var output=data[0]
      var container=data[1]
      return container
    },rej=>{
      console.log({rej})
      return rej
    }
  )
}
function getFile(container,file,ws){
  container.getArchive({path:file}).then(file=>{
    if(ws) ws.sendMsg(file) //send it somewhere I'm using a websocket. This will give you a stream with the tar file. 
//With the websocket you might have to parse the BufferList and iteratively send the buffers and assemble it on the other end
//fs.write(file,path,"UTF8") is another option. Though I think you still have to iterate the bufferList for "fs" 
  })
}
```

Don't forget to untar the file if you want to use it right away.

There is also a client side JavaScript package to untar the stream call [js-untar](https://www.npmjs.com/package/js-untar) that works well once you get it to the client side via websocket/other.

Comment: "I think you still have to iterate the bufferList for "fs"" could you point me to an example? I'm strugling to find the relevant documentation for this